# Как вывести две таблицы?

Tags: mysql

Всем привет! Есть две таблицы. Song и текст.
Структура Song. id, title. Структура текст. id,text,id_song.

Как вывести все песни, и не важно есть текст или нет.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT `a`.`id`, `a`.`title`, `b`.`text`
FROM `song` `a`
LEFT JOIN `song_text` `b` ON `a`.`id` = `b`.`id_song`
```